# CATiledLayer : Sample code

Tags: iphone, calayer, catiledlayer

I need to load the higher resolution image in UIImageView. After going through approaches seems like,If we load higher resolution images memory usage goes huge [ width * height * 4 ]
So to overcome this, need to implement CATiledLayer to support higher ones.
Referred PhotoScroller app,but they are using images from resource and I need to pick those images from Photo library.

Can anyone help me on this,how to implement this algorithm. any links or ref will be appriciated.

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good [example](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/catiledlayer_example) by Bill Dudney.